# Dynamic TAL provider: expressions

Tags: plone

How one can dynamically look-up providers in page templates in `` `structure provider:xxx ``?

Consider below non-working example

```xml
<div class="portlet-manager-row" tal:repeat="portletId python:range(1,5)">
    <div class="porlet-well_manager">
        <h2 i18n:translate="portlet-well-a">Portlet Well <b tal:content="portletId" /></h2>
        <tal:manager define="managerId string:ColophonPortlets${portletId}">
            <span tal:replace="structure provider:managerId" />
        </tal:manager>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part provider: fails because provider: assumes the input it always a direct string to provider name and does not seem to accept variables.

Comment: Edited the question to highlight the problematic part.

Comment: Maybe you can use someway the "path" TAL command, don't know if you can use the "provider:" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The TALES Provider Expression subclasses String Expression, so you should be able to do this:

```xml
<div class="portlet-manager-row" tal:repeat="portletId python:range(1,5)">
    <div class="porlet-well_manager">
        <h2 i18n:translate="portlet-well-a">Portlet Well <b tal:content="portletId" /></h2>

        <span tal:replace="structure provider:ColophonPortlets$portletId" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the string expression is superfluous, I moved and simplified the `$portletId` variable interpolation; for more complex string interpolations, use the `${expression}` syntax (e.g. `${request/providername}`).